# IE8-friendly bar chart with movable brush overlay?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, raphael, visualization, brush

I'm looking for a chart library that can generate something like this:

[image]

In other words, a dynamically generated bar chart, with a movable brush overlay - the user should be able to move the range by clicking and dragging, and that event should return the new limits of the brush.

I know how to do this in [D3.js with a brush overlay](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367), but I need to use an IE8-friendly JavaScript library.

Has anyone come across any examples using an IE8-friendly library - like Raphael for example?